# Conditions in while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, conditional-statements, lwjgl

Why this code works (Window closes on escape button)?

---

It looks that my post is mostly code, i dont know what details to add. It looks that my post is mostly code, i dont know what details to add.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
        {
            start(); //Create a window
            render(); //Run the game
            close(); //End the game
        }

    private static void start()
    {
        Window SD = new Window();
        SD.Launch();
    }

    private static void render()
    {
        while(!Display.isCloseRequested() && !Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE))
        {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        Display.update();
        }
    }

    private static void close()
    {
        Display.destroy();
    }
}
```

But this code does not:

```
//
while(!Display.isCloseRequested() && !Input.ESC)
//

public class Input
{
    public static boolean ESC = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second version, `Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)` is evaluated once and its value is assigned to `ESC`, which remains constant. It's either always true or always false (more likely).

Your first version evaluates `!Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)` on each iteration of the loop, so it can detect when ESC is actually pressed.

If you change ESC to be a static method instead of a static variable, your expression will be evaluate in each call to `ESC()` and both loops would work.

```
while(!Display.isCloseRequested() && !Input.ESC())
//

public class Input
{
    public static boolean ESC() 
    {
        return Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is this the best way?

Comment: @DaSH There isn't much difference between the two options (after you fix the second one).

Comment: @DaSH This is the same way that you use in your first version of your code. In this case a bit of memory need to be reserved for the method that just executes one line.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning to Input.ESC the value of Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard. KEY_ESCAPE) once and then in the while you're comparing always to the same value.

You need to evaluate Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard. KEY_ESCAPE) always you want to do the comparison.